# pyspark image dimension reduction with PCA

Tags: pyspark, pca

I am using Pyspark in AWS cloud to extract the image features:

```
ImageSchema.imageFields
img2vec = F.udf(lambda x: DenseVector(ImageSchema.toNDArray(x).flatten()),
                VectorUDT())
df_vec = df_cat.withColumn('original_vectors', img2vec("image"))
df_vec.show()
```

After having standardized the data:

```
standardizer = MinMaxScaler(inputCol="original_vectors",
                            outputCol="scaledFeatures",
                            min=-1.0,
                            max=1.0)
#withStd=True, withMean=True)
model_std = standardizer.fit(df_vec)
df_std = model_std.transform(df_vec)
df_std.show()
```

... when I apply PCA for dimension reduction, I receive an error that I could not debug for a couple of weeks :(

[Error_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHfGw.png)

[Error_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdi9G.png)

Could you please help me to solve that?

I use Pyspark spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7

Answer (score 1):

```
img2vec = F.udf(lambda x : Vectors.dense(x), VectorUDT())

df = df.withColumn("data_as_vector", img2vec("data_as_resized_array"))

standardizer = StandardScaler(withMean=True, withStd=True, inputCol="data_as_vector", outputCol="scaledFeatures")
```

for image it needs to **resize image data** with this code and you must use the resized image data;

```
def resize_img(img_data, resize=True):
    mode = 'RGBA' if (img_data.nChannels == 4) else 'RGB' 
    img = Image.frombytes(mode=mode, data=img_data.data, size=[img_data.width, img_data.height])
    img = img.convert('RGB') if (mode == 'RGBA') else img
    img = img.resize([224, 224], resample=Image.Resampling.BICUBIC) if (resize) else img
    arr = convert_bgr_array_to_rgb_array(np.asarray(img))
    arr = arr.reshape([224*224*3]) if (resize) else arr.reshape([img_data.width*img_data.height*3])

    return arr

def resize_image_udf(dataframe_batch_iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for dataframe_batch in dataframe_batch_iterator:
        dataframe_batch["data_as_resized_array"] = dataframe_batch.apply(resize_img, args=(True,), axis=1)
        dataframe_batch["data_as_array"] = dataframe_batch.apply(resize_img, args=(False,), axis=1)
        yield dataframe_batch

resized_df = df_image.select("image.*").mapInPandas(resize_image_udf, schema)
```

then you can make standardscaler and PCA with;

```
model_std = standardizer.fit(df)
df = model_std.transform(df)
# algorithm
pca = PCA(k=n_components, inputCol='data_as_vector', outputCol='pcaFeatures')
model_pca = pca.fit(df)

# Transformation images
df = model_pca.transform(df)
```

i think, i am too late to answer your questions, sorry